# mapping strings to array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, dictionary

I am trying to use the `containers.Map` function of MATLAB.

I want to map a string key to an array of two values like that:

```
x = {'0', '1'};
y=[[10,11],[5,6]];
map = container.Map(x,y);

[a,b] = map('0');
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error using containers.Map
The number of keys and values must be the same.

Error in test (line 7)
map = containers.Map(x,y)
```

The problem is that `y` is concatening the values of `a` and `b` such that:

```
y = [10, 11, 5, 6]
```

and thus the number of keys doesn't match to the values of the map.

How can I implement this correctly?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Perhaps try turning y into a cell array of vectors? `y = { [10, 11], [5,6]};`

Comment: That works ! but y is now a cell 

y = [1x2 double] [1x2 double] 

but i want to store it in [a,b] 

is that possible? sorry i am new in matlab

Comment: Yes, Y is now a cell in the form `Y = { [a,b], [a,b] }`.  When you access it from the container what do you get though? Do you get a cell containing the [a,b] vector, or do you get the vector itself?